# Android HTTP Response with different language characters

Tags: android, encoding, utf-8, httpclient, httpentity

I am working on basic HTTP request response example in Android. For this example project, I tried to work with Google Translate URL. However, the characters of other languages are replaced by junk or hex values in the response. If I hit the URL from desktop browser, it works fine.

Here is the code:

```
httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
httpGet = new HttpGet("https://translate.google.com/m?hl=en&sl=en&tl=gu&
    ie=UTF-8&prev=_m&q=sample") ;
httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity() ;
responseString = EntityUtils.toString( httpEntity, HTTP.UTF_8 );
// http response is all good except the characters that are in different 
// language are replaced by hex or junk characters.
```

What am I doing wrong? Any help?

Comment: Does the device supports Gujarati font natively? I found out in [this article](http://anirdesh.com/gujarati/add-gujarati-font-in-android.php) that not all devices have native support for Gujarati and some other languages.

Comment: Will check on that. But I am referring to http response in the string, even before it is displayed on the UI.

Comment: Andrew, it doesn't look like a issue with native fonts. The text render properly on mobile browser.